# Interacción Basada en Texto en un Asistente de Voz Python

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter

Mi código consiste en ser un asistente virtual que utiliza, primeramente, el reconocimiento de texto a voz para poder resolver preguntas y dudas, con algunas funcionalidades extras, como la consulta de la fecha y hora, para lo cual emplea la API de Google Bard, permitiéndole responder preguntas más complejas. También posee la capacidad de activarse al escuchar una frase específica, lo que le permite despertar y responder a tus preguntas. Sin embargo, si se le indica otra frase, entrará en un modo de suspensión y dejará de escuchar cualquier palabra que no sea su frase de activación.

En la actualidad, estoy desarrollando una interfaz de usuario que utiliza un cuadro de texto de tkinter para habilitar la comunicación con el asistente a través de texto. Al crear el cuadro de texto y asignar su valor a una variable, tenía la intención de utilizarlo como otra fuente de entrada para el asistente de voz. No obstante, me he dado cuenta de que no reconoce el texto que proviene del cuadro de texto de tkinter.

Inicialmente, declaré que la variable userInput tomaría el valor del texto que ingresara en el cuadro de texto: `userInput = input_text2.get()`. Luego intenté igualar este valor de userInput al valor de input_text, pero no funcionó. Posteriormente, investigué sobre las variables globales e intenté declarar `userInput` como global. Sin embargo, dado que la función `listen()` solo acepta la entrada de voz a través del micrófono, no sé cómo lograr que acepte dos fuentes de entrada, texto y voz, sin que una interfiera en el funcionamiento de la otra.

Esto es lo que añade el textbox de tkinter a la interface.

```py
# Input text box
input_text2 = tk.Entry(app, font=("Arial", 13), bg="#222121", fg="gray")
input_text2.place(x=60, y=42)
input_text2.config(width=40, borderwidth=0, insertbackground="white", insertwidth=1)

# Insert the placeholder text into the input text box
input_text2.insert(0, placeholder)

# Function to get the user input from the input text box
def get_user_input(event):
    global userInput
    userInput = input_text2.get()
    
    print(userInput)
```

Este es el codigo de la funcion de listen()

```
def listen():
    global input_text
    global userInput
    asleep = True  # Initialize sleep mode state
    while True:
        print("Listening for wake up word...")
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
            try:
                text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                if text.lower() == wake_up_word:
                    print("Listening for query...")
                    engineSay(selectedGreeting)
                    asleep = False  # Exit sleep mode
                    while True:
                        with sr.Microphone() as source:
                            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
                            try:
                                input_text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                                if input_text.lower() == sleep_mode_word:
                                    print("Sleep mode activated...")
                                    asleep = True  # Enter sleep mode
                                    break
                                elif "today" in input_text.lower() or "date" in input_text.lower():
                                    current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y")
                                    engineSay(f"Today is {current_date}.")
```

Gracias

Comment: Así mirándolo por encima diría que modificando tan solo dos líneas de una manera  muy sencilla debería de funcionar con un input de texto... lo cual me da la sensación de que esto no lo hiciste tú y quieres que ahora nosotros te lo modifiquemos "por la cara". De hecho, el texto de tu pregunta da la misma sensación. Te recomiendo que primero lo intentes tú mismo, porque aquí las preguntas que no demuestran un mínimo de esfuerzo e investigación no son bienvenidas, y en su estado actual tu pregunta no parece más que una tarea que nos estés poniendo sin haberte esforzado tú primero.

Comment: Si consideras que estoy equivocado, te invito a que utilices el botón [edit] y añadas más información sobre qué has intentado hacer y qué problema concreto tienes, porque poner un montón de código y decirnos *"Esto hace X, quiero que me digan cómo modificarlo para que haga Y"* no es una pregunta correcta en SO.

Comment: @Benito-B Gracias por el feedback, en relación al comentario. Reescribi la pregunta, explicando más los temas de mi pregunta.